# Two controllers same App, got error unregistered controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the situation:

This are snippets from the JS file main.js and the HTML file index.html:

```
angular.module("myApp", []); 

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("postController", function($scope) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Post";
})

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.ButtonStatus  = "OFF";
    $scope.myStyle = buttonGreen  //{'background-color':'#00FF00', 'font-size': '24px', 'width': '80px'}
    $scope.toggleRelay = function(){
        if($scope.ButtonStatus == "OFF")
        {
            $scope.ButtonStatus = "ON";
            $scope.myStyle = buttonRed;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.ButtonStatus = "OFF";
            $scope.myStyle = buttonGreen;   
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1 id="the-header">Wellcome to home electricity manager!</h1>
    <div add-row ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <span style="white-space:pre;">Button text</span><br/>
        <button id="first-button" ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()" id="switch-cirquit-1">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div add-row ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">   
        <span id="second-button" style="white-space:pre;">{{buttonOneText}}</span><br/>
        <button ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()" id="switch-cirquit-1">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="postController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <button>ASSS</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

After running this I get [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=post-changes-controller) error. The idea is to put two controllers under the same app, but it seems that it doesn't work that way. If I remove `postController` everything works fine. I read about how to use two controllers in the same app here for e.g. but that method doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to declare module with empty dependencies again, try this

```
angular.module("myApp", []); 

angular.module("myApp").controller("postController", function($scope) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Post";
})

angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function($scope) {
}
```

Comment: Try not to keep repeating "angular.module("myApp")". just save it in a variable and then reuse. Saves extra typing time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat this code `angular.module("myApp", []);`
Try this

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//use this code 
//and use this array ['$scope', function($scope) {}] so when you will build your code then you will not get any problem 

var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 

app.controller("postController",['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Post";
}]);

app.controller("myController", ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.ButtonStatus  = "OFF";
    $scope.myStyle = buttonGreen  //{'background-color':'#00FF00', 'font-size': '24px', 'width': '80px'}
    $scope.toggleRelay = function(){
        if($scope.ButtonStatus == "OFF")
        {
            $scope.ButtonStatus = "ON";
            $scope.myStyle = buttonRed;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.ButtonStatus = "OFF";
            $scope.myStyle = buttonGreen;   
        }
    }
}]);
```